# Why is the okhttp3.Response class final

Tags: java, unit-testing, okhttp

I'm trying to write unit tests for a class unit okhttp3 and I'm stuck at mocking the okhttp3.Response class.

It is declared final and most mocking frameworks can't mock final classes. 
I would rather NOT use Powermock just for this one.

Looking at the code I can see that it would be possible to create a real instance of the Response class and use it in the test but it would be much more code and much less readable compared to just mocking one method (in my case).

Any specific reasons behind the "final" modifier of the okhttp3.Response class or any plans to remove it in later releases?

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues ? Edit: From a quick glance it looks like they don't want to make their classes extensible as that lets them do changes much more easily. Also, would https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver be useful for you? There is a `MockResponse` class.

Comment: @Slanec at there github.com/square/okhttp/issues is an explicit reference to stack overflow for "questions". I can't believe I'm the first one to write a unit test for some coding using okhttp client and hitting this one.

Comment: Ah, I see, right. There might be some good solution for you, but you first need to say what you're trying to achieve and why. Why are you mocking the `Response`, would `MockWebServer` and `MockResponse` work well enough for you? If not, why?

Comment: @Slanec This seems to be the intended way to test OKHttp clients. On the positive side it is real since it opens a server socket, sends responses over a real network etc. On the negative side there is a risk of leaked sockets. You might as well add this as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Response` is a value class and thus should never be mocked. You can create instances with `Response.Builder` with whatever data you want the `Response` to have.

There are no plans to remove the `final` modifier.

Comment: But when I use the builder to make one for my tests I get "response is not eligible for a body and must not be closed" if I use try() autoclose.  Any advice?

Comment: I figured it out.  I mocked the ResponseBody in the Response object.